# changing document configuration with lyx

Tags: lyx

this is my first time with Lyx and what I wat to do is to change :

- the "Part" into chapter
- section 1 to section "ChapterNumber.sectionNumber"     (1.1)
- subsection 1 to   "chapterNumber.sectionNumber.subsectionNumber" (1.1.1)
  ....

and I want that those changes remain for the whole document
how should I proceed ?

Comment: You should read the help pages under the `Help` menu. You should also take a look into the `Documents->Settings...` menu.

Comment: I'm sorry that you've gotten so little response. You just need to change documentclass, under Document --> Settings --> Documentclass, to for example `report`. The chapter style will then be available, and you can change your parts to chapters.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using the default document class, which in LyX is set to `article`. This class does not have a Chapter style available, so instead of making the changes you have asked for in the `article` class, I think you should just change document class. In `report` or `book` the Chapter style is available, and the numbering of sections and subsections are as you ask.

Hence, go to Document --> Settings --> Document class, and choose **Report (Standard class)** or **Book (Standard class)** from the list. Then, for each of your parts, change the style to Chapter in the dropdown menu in the top left of the LyX window.